# Styling multiple jumbotrons - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want my homepage to feature multiple Jumbotrons, but when I try to style the Jumbotron class in my css.css file, they stylings are applied to each jumbotron. Without using inline css, how can I modify jumbotrons individually within my css file?

My css.css file, jumbotron class. Currently the changes are applied to both jumbotrons on my home page, when I just want the css below to be applied to the first.

```
.jumbotron{
    width:100%;
    height: 1400px;
    background-color:#f39c12;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-align: center;
}
```

My homepage. I would like the two jumbotrons to be different

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div id="firstJBox">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron">
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add another class for specificity..

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-special">
    <div id="firstJBox">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.jumbotron-special{
    width:100%;
    height: 1400px;
    background-color:#f39c12;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/122798

Answer (score 2):

Classes work, but they are meant to be re-usable. an ID seems more suited for this situation, since it is used to identify unique DOM objects, and can only be used once.

Answer (score 1):

Used this to work
html
`<div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotron-body"> </div>`

css
`.jumbotron#jumbotron-body { background-color: red; }`

Comment: Yes, you can accomplish this via classes (like the accepting answer proposes) or via ids